# CakePHP IDE with Auto Complete

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, phpstorm, cakephp-2.0

I was just wondering has anyone had any success in getting a IDE to work fully with CakePHP?  Typically in the past I've always used Netbeans.  The closest I've got is PhpStorm with the CakeStorm plugin, this allows me to click the uses in my plugins and it'll jump to them.

```
class NotificationShell extends AppShell{
    public $tasks = ['ShellModule.Notification'];
    public $uses = ['Systemsetting', 'Container'];
```

However what I really want is to be able to do a `$this->Container` press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> and it lists the options available in the Container Model, and if it could also list the magic find options `findById` would be great especially as a someone who is an old school PHP coder being dragged into the framework world.

I'm using CakePHP 2.8.3 and I'm willing to pay for an IDE with the functionality (it needs to run on Windows I'm afraid).

Comment: CakePHP uses magic for a lot of stuff. If CakeStorm plugin (dedicated for this framework) cannot help much here .. then the only other way is to describe such magic via `@property` and/or `@method` PHPDoc comments. You will find _some_ hints/howtos here: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpstorm+cakephp?sort=newest 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-760

Comment: If your IDE/editor supports `@property` and `@method` annotations then you will get autocompletions for those properties/methods. If you use `bake` to generate your classes it will create create files with those annotations.